# Locally install php Composer.phar in AMAZON Linux AMD

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I stuck with the question that i want to install php composer.phar locally in AWS Linux server for laravel 5.1.

I'm refereeing https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#locally and https://getcomposer.org/download/. As per this link follow bellow step

**Command:**

```
php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" > composer-setup.php
```

in output get the error that is

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/5.6/modules/pgsql.so' - /usr/lib64/php/5.6/modules/pgsql.so: undefined symbol: PQescapeLiteral in Unknown on line 0

As per the searching i got the link https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=702964 but yet didn't get the solution.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before running the php command, run the following

```
yum remove -y php56-pgsql
yum install postgresql-libs postgresql9-contrib
```

If you need to use php-pgsql you can now reinstall

```
yum install php56-pgsql
```